# javascript regex for region code

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex problem with validation for a region code.
My region code could be only one digit but it also could be a digits separated by '-'

for Example my region code could be one of the following:
6
6-66
77-7

As you can see I must have at least one digit or digits separated by '-' and if they are separated there should be a digits after the '-' sign (does not matter how many). So 6- must not be validated as legal region code. I try 2 hours to solve this, but I couldn't, so please help me! Thank you!

Comment: Show us some of your attempts. This is not the most elaborate of regex tasks. Have you checked out [a good tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/\d+(-\d+)?$/
```

This will match `6`, `6-66,`77-7`, but not`6-`

Comment: 10x. Can you explain what exactly ?$ do after the group()

Comment: @KaloyanStamatov The `?` makes the group optional.  The `$` anchors it to the end of the statement (i.e. `\d+` must be the end, or `-\d+` must be the end of it's there).  This prevents additional characters at the end.  You could also add `^` at the start to be even more specific

Answer (score 1):

If what you are looking for is the whole string:

```
/^\d+(?:-\d+)?$/
```

or something like that:

```
if (parseInt(yourstring.split(/-/)[0])>=eval(yourstring)) alert('true');
else alert('false');
```

But it is more complicated :) and less efficient! And if the condition is false you code will crash!

Comment: +1, but you probably also want to add anchors. This is about validating a string, not just finding a substring.

Comment: `/\d+(?:-\d+)?/.test('6-')` "true"

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = ['6', '6-66', '77-7', '6-'];

var len = data.length;

for(var i=0; i<len; ++i) {
  var current = data[i];
  var result = data[i].match(/^(\d+|\d+[-]\d+)$/);
  if(result != null) {
    console.log(current);
  }
}

--output:--
6
6-66
77-7
```

Answer (score 0):

For a quick answer you can try following:

```
 /^([0-9])|([0-9]\-[0-9][0-9])|([0-9][0-9]\-[0-9])$/
```

or in case your engine support perl-styled character classes:

```
 /^(\d)|(\d\-\d\d)|(\d\d\-\d)$/
```

here what it does:

1. between / and / resides as string defining a regular expression
2. \d stands for one digit it coudl also be writen as [0-9]
3. () defines a sub-expression, so (\d) matches your first one-digit, (\d-\d\d) second three digits style, and last (\d\d-\d) third variant of three-digit region code
4. | goes as "OR" like (A)|(B)|(C), so by combining previous three we will get:

   /(\d)|(\d-\d\d)|(\d\d-\d)/
5. Finally ^ means start of string, and $ - end of string.

also there is so called BRE mode (in which you have to add "\" symbol before each parentheses), but I think it is not the case. However if you would have some free time, please consider any quick tutorial like [this one](http://misc.yarinareth.net/regex.html).